# ui-grid-draggable-rows thinks my data is just a string

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I just followed the directions to get [ui-grid-draggable-rows](https://github.com/cdwv/ui-grid-draggable-rows) working. They show a working example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wayNOv).

My issue is that I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: this.splice is not a function

At this line of code:

```
this.splice(to, 0, this.splice(from, 1)[0]);
```

Just before the splice line, I log `this`:

```
console.log(this);
```

This is the output:

> app.Tasks

So it's a string literal. That would explain why `splice` isn't working. However, that string literal works in my ui-grid to display the tasks. This is in my angular controller:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'app.Tasks',
```

So what do I do to get this to work? It seems like a conflict if the draggable plugin treats the data as a literal string, yet the grid uses that literal string to point to the array of data.

Note: In the working example referenced above, they use a hard-coded array of data as the data for the grid. That's obviously okay for an example, but not for real-world use.

Edit - This is what app.Tasks looks like in the console:

[image]

Edit 2 - This is the entire code in appController:

```
function appController($scope, $http, $routeParams, uiGridConstants) {
    $scope.loading = 1;
    $scope.app = null;
    $scope.appId = $routeParams.appId;

    $scope.gridOptions = {
        data: 'app.Tasks',
        multiSelect: false,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false, // We don't want to have to click a row header to select a row. We want to just click the row itself.
        // Got the row template from https://github.com/cdwv/ui-grid-draggable-rows:
        rowTemplate: '<div grid="grid" class="ui-grid-draggable-row" draggable="true"><div ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader, \'custom\': true }" ui-grid-cell></div></div>',
        columnDefs: [{ field: 'Sequence', displayName: 'Order', width: "8%", resizable: true, sort: { direction: uiGridConstants.ASC, priority: 1 } },
                     { field: 'Description', displayName: 'Description', width: "62%" },
                     { field: 'PrestoTaskType', displayName: 'Type', width: "16%" },
                     { field: 'FailureCausesAllStop', displayName: 'Stop', width: "12%" }]
    };

    $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
        gridApi.draggableRows.on.rowDropped($scope, function (info, dropTarget) {
            console.log("Dropped", info);
        });
    };

    $scope.gridOptions2 = {
        data: 'app.CustomVariableGroups',
        multiSelect: false,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false, // We don't want to have to click a row header to select a row. We want to just click the row itself.
        columnDefs: [{ field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name', width: "98%", resizable: true }]
    };

    $http.get('/PrestoWeb/api/app/' + $scope.appId)
              .then(function (result) {
                  $scope.app = result.data;
                  $scope.loading = 0;
              },
              function () {
                  $scope.loading = 0;
                  alert("An error occurred and the app could not be loaded.");
              });
}
```

Comment: This may be kooky talk because I don't know Angular at all, but did you try assigning the actual object instead of the string? `data: app.Tasks`

Comment: I did try that before posting this question. If I do that, no tasks show up in my grid. Apparently angular needs the pointer to the variable in single quotes. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I'm over my head here, not knowing angular, so I'll stop making wild guesses! But I suspect it might be a set up issue -- can you post your whole initialization JS for the folks who DO know angular?

Comment: Gonna need more code to have any idea what is going on. We are using drag-drop just fine.  Try setting your items into a scope value and using that in the grid.  $scope.tasks = app.Tasks;   and then in the grid: data: $scope.tasks (no quotes)

Comment: Any time I do that, nothing shows up in the grid. I just tried this: `data: $scope.tasks`. No data in the grid. I just reverted to my original code and posted the controller code. It works as far as showing the data, but I'm back to my original issue of the draggable code choking on it.

Comment: I got the grid to display correctly by removing the data property from `$scope.gridOptions`. After retrieving the data, I set it manually: `$scope.gridOptions.data = result.data.Tasks;`. Now when I drag a row, the row doesn't actually stay where I drag it. The fromIndex and toIndex appear to both be -1. Grrr...

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but to get anything to work, I had to create my own draggable-row.js file and put this code in it: https://github.com/cdwv/ui-grid-draggable-rows/tree/master/js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by doing two things:

1. Remove setting the data property from within $scope.gridOptions.

   $scope.gridOptions = {
       //data: 'app.Tasks',  // deleted this line
       multiSelect: false
       // more properties assigned here
   };
2. Assign that property on its own line after getting the data.

   $scope.gridOptions.data = result.data.Tasks;